# Pull specific revision from master branch?

Tags: xcode, git

Im very new to Git and what I want to do with git within xcode is pull an older revision of my master (not commandline). Is this possible? I've looked in repositories under the organizer and i see all my commits there but i cant seem to load in one of them.

Comment: It is always better to do all operations with git from command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't go back to an earlier version of a repository from Xcode in Xcode 4. Older versions of Xcode allow you to go back to an earlier version of a repository, but older versions of Xcode lack git support.

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you have cloned/pushed your repo all the stuff you need is on your local drive.
If you want to see how code looks in specific commit, do

```
git checkout branch_name
```

or

```
git checkout 14646bf1a76d08cbda99317c4faa8de0072d6975
```

where branch_name can be alias for checksum used by git, (like `master` or `origin/master`), if you want to list your branch checksums you can do that by

```
git log
```

or if you want it in GUI use `qgit` `gitg` or my favourite `tig`, or whatever you'll find to list your commits

Comment: I wanted to do it in xcode and how can i specify a commit with only branch_name?